# Set a View variable in PostDispatch method of the Controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

How can I assign a view variable during the postDispatch method of the controller in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Your_Class extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

        $view = $layout->getView();

        $view->variable = 'some value';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way, because my class is extending base controller and the base controller is in turn extending Zend_Controller_Action. So, where do I extend Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract?

Comment: If you are extending Zend_Controller_Action then you should be able to write: $this->view->variable = 'some value'; in your class.

Comment: for some reason i am not able to read it in my view if i set it in postDispatch() of Controller. I am able to read it in preDispatch() though

Comment: I had no problem assigning a value to the view from postDispatch() either.  Did you debug to make sure the value being assigned is correct and/or set?  Also, what version of ZF are you using?